# PHP Xdebug profiler not tracing relevant functions

Tags: php, zend-framework, profiling, xdebug, xdebug-profiler

I have a PHP 7.1/Zend Framework 1 project running in a docker container with Xdebug 2.7 and I'm trying to figure out, why my PHP functions take up to 30 seconds. However the Xdebug profiler is only tracing framework/library internal functions. None of my own functions are visible in the call stack.

[image: Screenshot of the Xdebug cachegrind file in KCachegrind]

I would appreciate any suggestion that could help me solve my problem.

Comment: If only the framework calls show up, then it is possible that there is something that is over writing something else. I would try to configure the output file so that it includes a random number, by setting `https://xdebug.org/docs/all_settings#profiler_output_name` to `cachegrind.out.%p.%r`.

Comment: Thanks, that's actually a great idea, but unfortunately, it still only creates 2 files per call with the exact same content as before in both files.

Comment: What's in the second file?

Comment: The exact same as the first file.

Comment: It looks like these are only the calls in a registered shutdown handler. If you inspect the file contents itself, do other function calls appear too?

Comment: The only functions in the file are the ones that can be seen on the screenshot. The file is identical each time